# I am getting SqlException and DbUpdateException in the following question

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
var executionStrategy = _companyContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        using var transaction = await _companyContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
                        _companyContext.Set<CARILER_T>().Add(newEntity);
                        _companyContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT CARILER_T ON;");
                        await _companyContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        _companyContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT CARILER_T OFF");
                        await transaction.CommitAsync();
                    });
```

> I am getting the following errors in this and this codes

```
await strategy.ExecuteAsync
await _companyContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CARILER_T'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CARILER_T'. The duplicate key value is (536154).
> The statement has been terminated.
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes.
> See the inner exception for details.

Comment: What's the point of this code? The error you get is because you tried to insert a duplicate PK value. The code itself is not useful - `SaveChanges` persists *all* pending changes in an internal transaction already. There's no need for explicit transactions or `IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`. If you try to insert ID=1 twice, you'll get an error whether `ID` is database-generated or not

Comment: It is used in the update process

Comment: Execution strategies are meant for resilience cases when the driver or EF Core doesn't support this. Both SQL Server and the Pomelo EF Provider for MySQL provide resiliency strategies. There's no attempt to retry anything here

Comment: `It is used in the update process` what update process and why? `SaveChanges` alone works just fine. There's *no* way you can INSERT the same PK value twice though. If you want to attach a DTO that came from an HTTP request, you're doing it wrong. The EF Core documentation tutorials already show how this can be done - if the ID is database generated, simply calling `_companyContext.ThoseEntities.Add(newEntity)` works. The `newEntity` object will be tracked in the `Added` state. When `SaveChanges` is called, *all* new objects will be INSERTed in a single transaction

Comment: If you want to insert *or* update, use `Update` instead of `Add`. When the PK is database-generated, `Update` will track entities with a non-default PK value (eg >0) as `Updated` and those with a default (eg 0) as `Added`. When SaveChanges is called, the `Updated` entities will result in `UPDATE` commands. Again, all changes will run in a single database transaction

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why did you think you need to use an execution strategy and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ... OFF` ? Whatever the original problem is, it can't be solved this way and is probably already handled by EF in a different way

Comment: What problem? The real problem is all this code - it shouldn't exist at all. If you wanted to insert or update based on the key, **all** of this code should be replaced with just `_companyContext.Carilers.Add(newEntity);` and then, right before exiting the action, `await _companyuContext.SaveChangesAsync();`